# each link list has smaller array, does it make sense in C?

Tags: c, arrays, list, hyperlink

I want to create a program that creates link list which contains arrays.
However, I want each link to have a smaller array than previous one. at this moment the program works, but I want to know whether logically the program is actually creating smaller arrays, so no free space is wasted.

```
int main()

{
    int c=3;
    int d=0;

    typedef struct mylist {
        struct mylist *link;
        int info[c-d];
    }Node;

    Node *a = (Node*) malloc (sizeof (Node));
    a -> link = NULL;
    Node *b = a;
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (i!=4){
        while ((j)<=(2-d)){
            printf("link%d array%d  ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a->info[j]);
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        if (i !=3 ){
            a -> link = (Node*) malloc (sizeof (Node));
            a = a -> link;
        }
        d++;
        i++;
    }
    d=0;
    a = b;
    while (a != NULL){
        while ((j)<=(2-d)){
            printf("%d ->", a->info[j]);
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        d++;
        a = a -> link;
    }
    a=b;

    printf(" the end");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a weird construct..

Comment: Indent your code, please.

Comment: Please read about indentation first. That code is unreadable.

Comment: `int info[c-d];` .. `d++;` If you change the `d` after Typedef is meaningless. It is not possible to change the type that has already been determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're not `free()`ing memory which you allocated, make sure you take care of that.

Now, you're asking whether are you not using any additional memory - reading your code is pretty hard for us, as you can see in the comments. It is always a good idea to try it out yourself - find out the size of the memory occupied during the initialization of the structure, either with the sizeof() operator or with checking your values.

However, I don't think your code will work properly, due to the fact that you are statically initializing the arrays size. As the values are determined compile-time, this is completely fine. However, the problem is that you have already decided the size of the int array at the start.

If you want to use dynamic allocation of memory, you need to use the `malloc()` function. When creating a new node, you will have to allocate memory for an array in it as well (and calculate how much size you want to give it). This will also solve your problem of not knowing the size of the array or not being sure about it very well - as you are explicitly declaring how much memory you're allocating for the array.

Just a small addition though. When allocating for example 20 bytes of memory, the OS won't give you specifically 20 bytes - you'll get an entire page, which will often be more memory than necessary. So unless you're working with a device where controlling memory properly is really important or you're working with huge sizes of memory, you should not need to overthink the difference of the size of an array of 4 ints and 3 ints.

Comment: I am new to link-list and allocating memory in programming :( at this moment I know that you can create a link-list which contains a constant size like 6 --> 7 --> 8 or [4,5,6] --> [6,4,3] -->[5,6,7].
I want to know whether it is possible to create a link-list which can contain non constant size like [4,3,2] --> [2,3] -->[6]               this is what I am trying to do in this program but I think that my link-list works like this at this moment [4,3,5] --> [4,2,null] --> [5,null,null]

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is possible - and you want to use the `malloc()` function for it. `malloc()` returns a pointer to a block of memory with the size that you asked for. So what you want to do is allocate memory for the linked list node first and afterwards, allocate memory for the array inside of it. (int info[] would have to become int * info. afterwards you'd do a->info = malloc(sizeof(int)*size), where size would be the amount of integers you'd want the array to be able to store. For more information about using malloc, google will help you find many tutorials.

Comment: In particular, a "flexible array member" can be added to the end of the `struct` by defining the `info` member as `int info[];`. That works for C99 onwards. Some pre-C99-standard compilers also supported it, although in some of them you had to define it as a zero-length array (`int info[0];`). For those compilers that don't support a flexible array member or a zero-length array member, you can set the length to `1` instead. To determine the size of the structure with room for N elements, you can use the `offsetof` macro, e.g. `Node *a = malloc(offsetof(Node, info[c-d]));`.